# How can I remove white space in between content and footer in JQuery Mobile hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

A quick introduction is in order. I'm newer to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and am currently working on using HTML5 and Jquery Mobile to develop a "hybrid" app. I've been doing pretty well trouble shooting my problems until now.

I have run into an issue where my content of a page is not long enough so a white space appears between the content and the fixed footer. I've tried multiple solutions including all of the ones listed [here](http://cerulli-dharaharsh.blogspot.com/2013/08/remove-jquery-mobile-white-space-after_27.html) and none seem to work (granted, I may have been implementing them wrongly).

[image]

It is worth noting that the issue does not seem to be only contained in the index.html file as it persists as I navigate pages, though the extra white space is a different size. It is also worth noting that the white space is also underneath the footer (so if I tap the page to make the footer disappear momentarily it shows white not the background color).

Here is the index.html file (which the problem is occurring in and the image is showing).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/The_Greens/The_Greens.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/The_Greens/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Add .structure after theme-->

        <!-- Jquery core -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Jquery mobile library file -->
        <script src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Scripts (pre-load)-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <title>SYNCTFY</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<!-------------------------------------------------------PERSISTANT HEADER---------------------------------------------------------->
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" style="height:40px" data-theme="e">
                <a href="#logout" data-icon="info">Log out</a>
                <h1 style="font-size: 20px" class="ui-title" role="heading">SYNCTFY</h1>
                <a href="#settings" data-icon="gear">Settings</a>
            </div>

<!--------------------------------------------------------Home Page----------------------------------------------------------------->

        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="Home" data-theme="e">
            <!--------------------------------------------Content------------------------------------------------------->

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
                <a href="biblereadings.html" data-role="button">Bible Reading</a>
                <a href="biblestudy.html" data-role="button">Bible Study</a>
                <a href="prayerpaths.html" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Prayer Paths</a>


            </div>

        </div>

<!-----------------------------------------------------PERSISTANT FOOTER------------------------------------------------------------>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="fade">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="events.html" data-icon="home" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="flip">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="news.html" data-icon="home" data-prefetch="true" data-transition="slide">News</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Scripts (post-load)-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I apologize for asking such a popular question again, however I can't seem to find a solution that actually fixed this issue. Hopefully with the information I provided I can solve my problem and help others looking for the same solution.

Additional Info:
-The css files all all defaults, except for the css files generated by themeroller (which have not been modified).

I am using:
Visual Studio 2013
Jquery Mobile 1.4.2
Phonegap 3.5.0

**Update:**
Opening my index.html file in firefox makes the app work perfectly, however if I open it in internet explorer it shows the white space. This would make sense since my app is targeting a windows phone which uses IE as the browser. I'm using IE 11 on my desktop to trouble shoot so it isn't an older version. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to set the page height like `.ui-page{min-width: 100%}`?

Comment: I copy pasted your code it shows like http://jsfiddle.net/3p9jy/

Comment: try to change like this http://jsfiddle.net/wM8Zm/619/

Comment: Increase min-height of page e.g. .ui-page{min-height:580px;}

Comment: You need to override the default JQM css class . try this .ui-overlay-a, .ui-page-theme-a {
background-color:black;//assign color your given to ui-content
}

Comment: Sadly, none of these seemed to fix my issue. I created a separate css file and placed it beneath the existing css files included within my html file because I read that that would override existing css. I tried each of these solutions in the css file separately and they didn't work. I'm wondering if I am not implementing these fixes correctly? Or if I have a deeper issue than I realize.